# How do I POST a List<T> in ASP.NET MVC, and have the model work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following class that I'd like to display in a form and allow it to POST to ASP.NET MVC running on a different server.

I have all the attributes working correctly, however I can't get List to work

```
public class TokenCreateConfirm
{
    public string UIDPName { get; set; }

    public TokenCreateConfirm()
    {
       Attributes = new List<Attr>();
    }
    public string ProverURL { get; set; }

   public List<Attr> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

How should I render the `Attributes` List variable in a FORM so it POSTs correctly to ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: What did you try so far? are you using `EditorTemplates`? does the target Action expects a parameter of type `TokenCreateConfirm`?

Comment: I don't understand how editorTemplates will render List<T> or what the resulting HTML Form output will be.  So far I'm thinking I need to serialize the type and save it as JSON text in a hidden field.

Comment: NOTE: I'm not expecting to allow the user to edit the list, this is read only for all intents and purposes, though I would be academically interested in a Read/Write approach

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Attributes)` would output nothing unless you explicitly define a specific Template.

Comment: @makerofthings7 how your Attributes  rendered in html dom.. i mean radios , dropdowns or else?

Comment: @vishalsharma I can render them in any way.  So far I hacked a solution where I take all the elements in a hidden input, delimited by &.  I then split the string after the POST.

Comment: if you are using element like radio button list with same name and have values bound to that.. then if you access Request.Form.Get('radiobuttonnameattr') will give you comma separated items that you can use .. idea is give your html control same name attribute and it will create comma seperated list

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx):

```
for(int i=0;i<Model.Attributes.Count;i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attributes[i].PropertyName)
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to edit an exising attribute list, you first make an `EditorTemplate` for your `Attr` class, `Shared/EditorTemplates/Attr.cshtml` :

```
@model MyNamespace.Attr

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Prop1)

// Add whatever fields from Attr, you can also you drop down lists or checkboxes
```

Then in your main view, you can use it like this :

```
@model MyMainNamespace.tokenCreateConfirm

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UIDPName)

// Display or edit other simple properties as you like

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attributes)
```

What happens there is that the view engine will look for a template called `Attr.cshtml` in your `Shared/EditorTemplates` folder, then apply it to every element of your list. This way, it is correctly named when the html is generated, and you get your values back when you submit your form :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveInput(TokenCreateConfirm token)
{
    var attributes = token.Attributes;
    // ...
}
```